# Update a dataframe using new information for some rows, but keeping all the old information also

Tags: r, dataframe, join, dplyr

I have several dataframes that I'm using to create maps. These dataframes are updated daily but only some of the rows are updated. So each new dataframe only contains a subset of rows of the original dataframe.
The first df contains the spatial info

```
head(boxes)
  Name       lon      lat
1   B1 -1.308810 51.76481
2  B10 -1.309306 51.76457
3 B100 -1.308591 51.76488
4 B101 -1.308725 51.76464
5 B102 -1.308454 51.76439
6 B103 -1.308270 51.76412
```

The next df contains some extra info

```
head(boxes0604)
  Name Section       lon      lat State.code Clutch.size
1   B1       b -1.308810 51.76481          0           0    
2  B10       b -1.309306 51.76457          1           0    
3 B100       b -1.308591 51.76488          0           0    
4 B101       b -1.308725 51.76464          0           0    
5 B102       b -1.308454 51.76439          0           0    
6 B103       b -1.308270 51.76412          0           0
```

and I can combine these easily enough using `dplyr` and `left_join` and plot my first map

Now let's say that I get some new info only regarding a subset of the info in my next dataframe `boxes0804`

```
head(boxes0804)
  Name Section         State.code Clutch.size
1 B108       b            0           4    
2 B211       b            1           6    
3 B219       b            4           12    
4 B237       b            4           8    
5 B287       b            4           7    
6 B291       b            4           11
```

You can see that this df does not contain the spatial info and only some of the rows contained in `boxes0604`

What I would like to do, in order to plot this new info on top of the old info from `boxes0604` is combine these data sets to import only the new information and keep all of the old information. When I try to join them I lose all the information from the new df. Perhaps I'm using the `join` functions incorrectly.

thanks in advance

Comment: you tried other join methods ? like `full_join` from `dplyr`

Comment: Tried them all, just can't seem to get the result I want. It usually ends up just keeping all the old info without adding the new

Comment: I suggest you to use `merged <- cbind(old,new)` if you are sure about the order of data frames (and row numbers,of course), if you are not set an order then `cbind` them all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you'd like to merge `boxes0804` into your existing data, but only for rows where the Name appears both in the existing data and `boxes0804`.  My suggestion would be to merge only such rows, as follows, using data.table:

```
boxes <- setDT(boxes)
boxes0804 <- setDT(boxes0804)
# First keep the rows without a match
boxes_nomatch <- boxes[! Name %in% boxes0804$Name]
# Now merge on the new rows, where there is a match
boxes_match <- merge(boxes[Name %in% boxes0804$Name], boxes0804, by = "Name", all.x = TRUE)
boxes_updated <- rbind(boxes_nomatch, boxes_match)
```

It is a little hard to do this without a reproducible example: [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), but I think this is what you're going for.

Comment: Yes apologies writing this from my phone. I'll try that